# Ошибка при попытке запуска cordova на устройстве

Tags: android, cordova

Не получается запустить тестовое приложение на устройстве
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас cordova для андроид проекта выставила таргет sdk - API22, который у вас отсутствует на машине. Либо выкачайте с помощью SDK менеджера SDK для api 22, либо измените в cordova настройки для андроида.

Comment: спс сделал так вроде помогло